# How does one implement the e-maling option for slurm?

Tags: slurm

I am using slurm in a cluster and when I turn on the e-mailing option it does not work. Is there any special type of administering I need to do to turn it on in my cluster?

My sample submission script for `sbatch`:

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --mail-user=rene_sax14@yahoo.com
#SBATCH --array=1-1
#SBATCH --partition=debug
#SBATCH --time=4:00:00
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=16
#SBATCH --sockets-per-node=1
#SBATCH --cores-per-socket=4
#SBATCH --threads-per-core=4
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=1200
#SBATCH --export=ALL
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:v100:1


nvidia-smi

echo DONE
```

Answer (score 1):

Slurm expects the `MailProg` option in `slurm.conf` to refer to the

> Fully qualified pathname to the program used to send email per user request. The default value is "/bin/mail" (or "/usr/bin/mail" if "/bin/mail" does not exist but "/usr/bin/mail" does exist).

so you need that command to work. You can install Postfix for instance to relay the emails to your outgoing SMTP server.

Often, the value of `MailProg` is set to `smail`, a script available in the ['contribs' section of the Git repository](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/tree/master/contribs), in directory `seff`:

```
  seff/              [Tools to include job include job accounting in email]
     Expand information in job state change notification (e.g. job start, job
     ended, etc.) to include job accounting information in the email. Configure
     Slurm's MailProg to "smail" from this package.
```